# Checking the size of file before uploaing it

Tags: javascript

Is there is any way to check file size before uploading it using javascript?

Answer (score 6):

Only on some browsers. There's a [new API from the W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-upload/) that allows *very limited* access to the file system from client-side Javascript in the browser. It works by having the user explicitly allow you access to the file by selecting it in an `<input type='file'>` field. You can then query its properties (*not* including its full path) and even read it directly without sending it to the server.

The File API was originated by Mozilla and is supported by Firefox 3.6 upward (earlier versions supported an earlier version of it). Chrome and Safari also have it, I believe. [Here's an article about it](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/12/w3c-fileapi-in-firefox-3-6/) by Arun Ranganathan from Mozilla.

So you could try to use it, and if it's there, great; if not, you're stuck with not being able to do this on the client.

Naturally you **will** want to impose any file size restrictions on the server *as well*, regardless of whether you can do it on the client. Client-side validation is *always* a convenience, never a substitute for defending your server.

Answer (score 2):

No - javascript does not have access to the file system. If you can use a flash or silverlight gadget to do your uploads, you would be able to do this.

Comment: Javascript **does** have access to the file system now! On most of the major browsers.

Comment: That's pretty cool. Unfortunately it seems that "most of the major browsers" excludes IE (surpising, I know...). So for most applications, the answer is still 'no' for now.

Comment: Yup, no IE support yet -- but we're talking very early days, and the process around IE9 is looking quite different from Microsoft's approach to standards in the past, so here's hoping. I'd say the answer for most applications *isn't* "no," it's "use it if it's there but be ready if it isn't" which, if you think about it, is true of so much of web standards at the moment. :-) And since you need server-side validation *anyway*...

Comment: makes sense - I could use the file size checking in a few spots - I think I'll give it a try

Answer (score 0):

no.

And its a Royal PITA. The best you can do is set filesize limits on your receiving end, and have adequete validation to notify the user when they have tried to upload something too big.